# Unity C# if statement fails?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, if-statement

I'm trying to learn Unity to try and pursue my dream job of being a game designer. I came across a weird thing that I don't understand why it doesn't seem to work.

Essentially I have a turn based battle system that otherwise works, but I'm trying to add a turn limit. What I have set up is basically:

```
int Clock = 5;

Clock--;

if (Clock <= 0)
{
    EndCombat();
}
```

It never seemed to end combat, despite successfully updating the health bars that is done right before the if statement. I tried several things such as putting `0 >= Clock` instead of `Clock <= 0`,  changing text in the HUD to see if the if statement is even triggering, I've even just set `Clock = 0` right before the `if` statement, but it doesn't seem to trigger and I can't figure out why.

Currently it sets Clock to 5, then after any turn (player or enemy) it does `Clock--;` and then calls this method:

```
void UpdateCombatHUD()
{
    LeftHUD.SetHpAndMp(LeftUnit);
    RightHUD.SetHpAndMp(RightUnit);
    Timer.text = "Time: " + Clock;

    if (Clock <= 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(HELLO());

        if (LeftUnit.CurrentHp > RightUnit.CurrentHp)
        {
            state = CombatState.Won;
            EndCombat();
            return;
        }
        else if (LeftUnit.CurrentHp < RightUnit.CurrentHp)
        {
            state = CombatState.Lost;
            EndCombat();
            return;
        }
        else if (LeftUnit.CurrentHp == RightUnit.CurrentHp)
        {
            state = CombatState.Draw;
            EndCombat();
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

`LeftHUD.SetHpAndMp` makes sure the player's Hp and Mp bars are accurate.

`RightHUD.SetHpAndMp` makes sure the enemy's Hp and Mp bars are accurate.

`StartCoroutine(HELLO());` is supposed to display a message and then wait 5 seconds before it does anything else (I used this to try and help me figure out what the problem is, but `StartCoroutine(HELLO())` is never triggered).

Someone asked about `EndCombat()` and if that helps here it is:

```
void EndCombat()
{
    switch (state)
    {
        default:
            return;
        case CombatState.Won:
            DialogueText.text = "A winner is you!!!";
            break;
        case CombatState.Lost:
            DialogueText.text = RightUnit.Name + ": Git Gud Scrub!!!";
            break;
        case CombatState.Draw:
            DialogueText.text = "Wow, a tie ... that's akward ...";
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't know what changed, but i was testing the code with a change somewhere else, and it displayed the victory text while Clock was in the negative, but then it kept going. so it seems like it's kinda solved?

nevermind, i add some code that should change scenes, but it never changed scenes

Comment: It's hard to tell without more code, but if that's a direct copy from a method, then you'll never hit the trigger because you're always initializing the Clock variable to 5 and subtracting 1, so its value will always be 4 in the if statement.

Comment: Please post the whole code.

Comment: sorry, i tried to shorten it to be direct and to the point, let me update the question

Comment: @Kolichikov

does this help?

Comment: clock = clock -1; can u try this insted of clock-- ? and are u sure that clock = 5 is written away from your code where you call this method?

Comment: What's the function that calls Clock-- (unless I missed it, nothing adjusts clock in the UpdateCombatHUD method). Also have you put a Debug.Log to see if Clock is ever changing?

Comment: @AhmedAlayat clock is set to 5 in a method that is only called once

Comment: @Kolichikov Clock-- only comes up the line before about half of the instances where UpdateCombatHUD is called

as for Debug.Log, no, but it is a public int that is attacked to a gameobject that i open in the inspector, and it does go to zero

Comment: does the Timer.text get changed?

Comment: @AhmedAlayat yup, Timer.text accurately changes, even goes into the negatives while i'm testing this possible way of ending combat. also just tested if changing every instance of Clock-- to Clock = Clock - 1, end this didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: can we see the EndCombat (); definition, I can't see it anywhere

Comment: @A.Njuguna just added EndCombat() to the end of the question

Comment: Please post your complete code as a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)!

Comment: @derHugo sorry for the long haitus, life happened

the code is based off of brackey's turn based combat video, if that helps, i'll try to update the question with the minimal reproducible example soon ... if that's okay? i guess?